# Converting text file from ANSI to ASCII using C#

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, ascii

I have an ANSI-encoded file, and I want to convert the lines I read from the file to ASCII.

How do I go about doing this in C#?

---

**EDIT :** What if i used "BinaryReader" 
`BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(input, Encoding.Default);`
but this reader takes (Stream, Encoding)
but "Stream" is an abstract! And where should I put the path of the file which he will read from ?

Comment: Why do you think that you want to convert it to ASCII? The answer to that may reveal what you actually should convert it to...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A direct conversion from ANSI to ASCII might not always be possible, since ANSI is a superset of ASCII.

You can try converting to UTF-8 using `Encoding`, though:

```
Encoding ANSI = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

byte[] ansiBytes = ANSI.GetBytes(str);
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(ANSI, Encoding.UTF8, ansiBytes);

String utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```

Of course you can replace UTF8 with ASCII, but that doesn't really make sense since:

- if the original string doesn't contain any byte > 126, then it's already ASCII
- if the original string does contain one or more bytes > 126, then those bytes will be lost

**UPDATE:**

In response to the updated question, you can use `BinaryReader` like this:

```
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open("foo.txt", FileMode.Open),
                                       Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
```

Answer (score 23):

Basically, you need to specify an `Encoding` when reading/writing the file. For example:

```
// read with the **local** system default ANSI page
string text = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.Default); 

// ** I'm not sure you need to do this next bit - it sounds like
//  you just want to read it? **

// write as ASCII (if you want to do this)
File.WriteAllText(path2, text, Encoding.ASCII);
```

Note that once you have read it, `text` is actually unicode when in memory.

You can choose different code-pages using `Encoding.GetEncoding`.

Comment: Good answer, particularly for pointing out that you can use the static File methods and don't need to directly involve FileStreams or buffers.